# Group/Ungroup Excel functionality in WinForms Grid

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, gridcontrol

I want to achieve the following functionality for an XtraGrid. This is taken from Excel 2010 and is the action of Grouping from (Data -> Group Rows).

[image]
[image]

The solution I have so far is to use Master-Detail functionality of the XtraGrid, but I already use to "link" existing row to another row, creating a parent-child relation between them. Using the Master-Detail for the grouping displayed above would mix up the linking with the grouping. This could be ok but I want to somehow separate them visually.

To achieve the + and - signs and the vertical dark bar in the left I thought of adding an additional column in the Grid that contains either the imagine of a dark vertical line or a button.

Any help is much appreciated.

(If this question has been posted before and answered please point me in that direction and delete this thread).

Thank you and have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Sir in `gridView` please set `ShowGroupPanel` property to `true` then in columns properties set `GroupIndex` to group by this columns